# Pulling data from API that disappears when added to pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api

So I have connected to bybits API and pulled some data that I'm trying to add to a pandas data frame. The original data is fine until I use the pandas data frame, this leads to some values missing. I'm new to coding and have tried solving / searching this problem myself but have had no luck. Any help is very much appreciated.

---

This is the output of the original data pulled from the API:

*{'ret_code': 0, 'ret_msg': 'OK', 'ext_code': '', 'ext_info': '', 'result': [{'id': 28175809, 'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'period': 'D', 'interval': 'D', 'start_at': 1641168000, 'open_time': 1641168000, 'volume': 87839.49, 'open': 3826.2, 'high': 3861.9, 'low': 3681.35, 'close': 3761.95, 'turnover': 332049170.8095}], 'time_now': '1652781721.802819'}*

---

This is the output with the added data frame:

*ret_code ret_msg ext_code ext_info  

0         0      OK

0  {'id': 28175809, 'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'period'...  1652781995.652047*

---

As you can see there are many values missing when using the data frame

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pybit import usdt_perpetual


session = usdt_perpetual.HTTP(
    endpoint='https://api.bybit.com', 
    api_key='',
    api_secret=''
)


data = (session.query_kline(
    symbol= "ETHUSDT",
    interval= "D",
    limit= 1,
    from_time= 1641085261
))


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data).join(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['result'])).drop('result',axis=1)
```

Comment: Wow that works! thanks very much. where was I wrong in my thinking?